# Encountering high memory usage on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, performance, troubleshooting

I'm using a [laptop](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/GE60-2PC-Apache/Specification) with 8GB of ram and am encountering high idle ram usage, when previously I was able to open tabs upon tabs of google Chrome right now about 15 tabs will cause Chrome crash already. I've googled and read some solutions and tried them out to little success. With that, I'm attaching screenshots of things like task manager, rammap and poolmon to hopefully give you an idea of what's happening.

[image]

[RAMMap 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8OeV.png)

[RAMMap 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgH9W.png)

[Poolmon with non-paged and bytes on top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJUNy.png)

[CMD of top of Poolmon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIuqJ.png)

I notice that it probably isn't because of a driver leak, and the top is ismc(Intel Rapid Storage) and another is ConT(No idea what) which takes up 3MB from what I know? I could be wrong as I don't really know what I'm looking at. If any more information has to be provided I will be ready to provide them.

Answer (score 0):

Tag says Windows 10 so assume 64-bit. Task Manager (above) says 4 GB of memory are in use (at idle you say).

That is entirely normal. Windows 7 64-bit, Windows 8 64-bit and Windows 10 64-bit all idle along using approximately 4 GB or memory.

So normal, and nothing to worry about.

Comment: It would be interesting to know how many svchost processes you've got running at the moment, but I notice you're using only one of your two RAM slots, which means your RAM is running single-channel. That alone would explain the high overheads, because your RAM pages are all on the same chip. Try this: in Regedit, go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control, locate (or create, if it doesn't exist) the SvcHostSplitThresholdInKB DWORD and change/set its value to 8388608 from the (probable) default 380000 then restart your PC and tell us how you're doing, RAM-wise.

Comment: I see, thank you! I recalled watching [Linus video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HnuNs_Nu46Q) about how 8gb of ram could manage about 25 tabs open at a single time, and I've definitely opened more last time than I am able to now.

Comment: @Didier Alright, I'll be trying that tomorrow and be letting you know that goes. Thanks for the help! The single channel is due to the laptop preinstalled with a single channel RAM.

Comment: You could have dozens of SVC hosts running and it is difficult to find which one is causing an issue.

Comment: @John : exactly, and raising the split threshold would help by reducing the overall number of those svchost processes. If it doesn't make the situation better, it's easy to go back to the default value, but raising the threshold is harmless and has been known to work wonders on systems that had gone slow over time.

Comment: Also, since Vista (the first generally used 64-bit operating system) , 4 GB is the normal idle memory used level. It has been that was for me on all the machines I have used going back to 2008.

Comment: I think Windows's memory management algorithms work along the same "unused RAM is lost RAM" lines as Apple's when it comes to consumer products (OS). For example, I'm posting from Windows Server 2019, and at the moment, only 50 % of my 6GB, DDR3, dual-channel RAM is in use, with Firefox gobbling over 1.2GB, the glut... Services are mostly working on idle, and I have qBittorrent running in the background, but I still have over 3GB of unused RAM to play with. In Windows 7-to-10, it's different: the more RAM you have, the more the OS will preempt, for itself or "just in case"...

Comment: What I see is 4 GB used and all remaining as "Available"

Comment: Most of the time, most of the 4 GB available is used as "Standby" for unknown processes I can't find in RAMMap. I have edited my split threshold and for now I've noticed little difference, thank you for the help though! As least I know I have done something to optimize my system.


So from what I can tell 4 GB of idle RAM usage is normal am I right? The problem is when I play games or anything they state that around 2 GB more is "available" but Chrome/Game starts crashing or slowing down and task manager says system is running out of memory.

Comment: You asked "So from what I can tell 4 GB of idle RAM usage is normal am I right?"   Yes.  That is entirely normal.  Then you asked "The problem is when I play games ….  Chrome/Game starts crashing"  That could be something about the game, or just that for your use, 8 GB is not enough.